# LitElement: How to populate a slot inside a vaadin overlay

Tags: vaadin, lit-element, vaadin-flow, lit

I'm following [this tutorial](https://vaadin.com/labs/lit-element) to create my component.
In my usecase I'd need to add a Java element to a slot inside a vaadin-overlay.

```
<vaadin-overlay id="myOverlay">
    <slot name="myslot"></slot>
</vaadin-overlay>
```

I guess there is some sort of timing problem because when I try to add a component to that slot it is not shown.

```
Component component = ...
component.getElement().setAttribute("slot", "myslot");
add(dropdownEndSlot);
```

Or is that not possible within an overlay?

**Update 31/08/2021:**
There is now a code sample in [the sampler](https://github.com/hons82/vaadin_sampler/commit/9b49a0220b0a7578fd49de88eb7c5d219e1d2975) for you to test and see

**Update 09/09/2021:**
I've now completely rewritten the whole component to litelement and updated [the sampler](https://github.com/hons82/vaadin_sampler/commit/2e75673ae233a47c307386672161a3c3c7cbb8e4). It is working as far as I can see, but... still a bit slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vaadin overlay, once opened, teleports the contents to the 'real' overlay element (the one that's shown) - created outside any shadowRoot.
It seems this is a frequent issue, it turns out that it is not possible to use slots inside an overlay (https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-dialog/issues/11
).

As for the "dropdownEndSlot", for example for vcf-autosuggest component it has been overcome like this:

```js
<div id="dropdownEndSlot" part="dropdown-end-slot"></div>
```

and then filled in the backend.

```java
    @Id(value = "dropdownEndSlot")
    private Element dropdownEndSlot;

    public void clearDropdownEndSlot() {
        dropdownEndSlot.removeAllChildren();
        dropdownEndSlot.getStyle().set("display", "none");
    }

    public void setComponentToDropdownEndSlot(Component component) {
        clearDropdownEndSlot();
        dropdownEndSlot.getStyle().set("display", "block");
        dropdownEndSlot.appendChild(component.getElement());
    }
```

It is not a perfect solution though, but something like this might do it:

```java
@Route("")
public class TestView extends VerticalLayout {
    public TestView() {
        CustomComponent cc = new CustomComponent();

        Div testElement = new Div(new Span("IT WORKED !!!!"));
                testElement.setId("IT-WORKED");


        cc.addSlot001Content(testElement);
        cc.openOverlay();
        add(cc);

    }
}
```

```java
@Tag("custom-component")
@JsModule("./custom-component.ts")
public class CustomComponent extends LitTemplate {
    @Id(value = "overlay")
    private Element overlay;

    @Id(value = "slot001")
    private Element slot;

    public void openOverlay() {
        overlay.setAttribute("opened", "true");
    }

    public void addSlot001Content(Component component) {
        slot.appendChild(component.getElement());
    }
}
```

```js
import { LitElement, html, customElement } from 'lit-element';

@customElement('custom-component')
export class CustomComponent extends LitElement {
    render() {
        return html`
            <vaadin-overlay id="overlay">
                <div id="slot001"></div>
            </vaadin-overlay>`;
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently I can't get that to run. I have it in the shadow dom, but it doesn't get rendered. Maybe I need to create the overlay as opened and close it later?

Comment: I've added a sample code to my sampler to show the problem (the code might look familiar to you :-) ), if you have an idea let me know

Comment: Yeah, it is really not filling the slot once opened, I'm having a look at it !

Comment: I edited the answer so it should be more helpful now.